# GotoVisibleTab crashes on Android when using Slide transition

Tags: android, firemonkey, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I'm using **FMX.TabControl.TTabControl.GotoVisibleTab** without any problem on 10.2 Tokyo release 1 and on 10.1 Berlin. However, since Tokyo release 2, the same code is crashing when executed on an Android target. There is no problem on Windows or iOS targets. When I use **None** instead of **Slide** as transition mode, the problem also disappears.

I've checked the problem occurence with a minimal project (1 TabControl with 2 TabItems). I've also searched on several forums but found nothing...

```
procedure TForm1.NextTab;
var
  TabIdx : integer;
begin
     with TabControl1 do
     begin
          TabIdx:=TabIndex;
          if TabIdx < (TabCount-1) then inc(TabIdx) else TabIdx:=0;
             GotoVisibleTab(TabIdx,TTabTransition.Slide,TTabTransitionDirection.Normal);
     end;
end;
```

Could you help me ?

Answer (score 1):

it is a bug in firemonkey, use ttabtransition.none innstead

i hope they will fix it one day